# Blocking Standard Users (Win 10) from Adding Chrome Extensions

Tags: chrome, windows-10, browser-extensions

I want to block standard users (Win 10) from adding Chrome extensions. When the standard user renames the default folder, it overwrites any security policies applied on the Extensions folder.

Answer (score 2):

Use Group Policy. This is [supported by chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en).

It's [fairly well documented](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallBlacklist) how to do this:

> Allows you to specify which extensions the users can NOT install. Extensions already installed will be disabled if blacklisted, without a way for the user to enable them. Once an extension disabled due to the blacklist is removed from it, it will automatically get re-enabled.
>
> A blacklist value of '*' means all extensions are blacklisted unless they are explicitly listed in the whitelist.

There's more settings you can make, such as whitelisting or forcing specific extensions. Don't try to conjure up your own scheme by using custom permissions on parts of chrome user profile directory.

Comment: "by using custom permissions on parts of chrome user profile directory", directory where user has full right by default and could mess hard and bypass your attempt